# Assign array collection items to object proxy properties in action script (flash builder)

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3

I am trying to pass object to a web service. My generated proxy classes has got all the properties and my sql statement return a array collection. what I want is to map the items in the array collection to appropriate property of the object proxy and post it to web service.

ObjectProxy.MdId = SQLResult[d].MD_ID;

there will be variable number of the properties for each class (but the sql result collection will always match the object proxy). I want to do the mapping automatically instead of mapping them manually.

thanks

Comment: this is my properties inside generate classes  model_internal static var allProperties:Array = new Array("AdId", "AdMdId", "AdAudio", "AdDeviceTimestamp", "AdServerTimestamp");

Comment: how can I access these VARs outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it is a good Idea but anyways I can call it a work around, I am now accessing the collectionProperties of the metadata model and assigning it to an array and use the array for other purposes. the idea behind this implemntaion is that I have 20 different entities and all of the has got different properties, if I hard code the properties I had to write lots of stuff, Now i get the array which is already generated on the clases and just pass that to my method for process.

```
private var _AudioData:MobileAudioData =  new MobileAudioData();
var Properties:Array = _AudioData._model.getCollectionProperties();
```

hope this helps someone else too.

Comment: where MobileAUdioData is a service on .net side and the proxy class for it generate in flash builder.